Latex error: Package array Error: Illegal pream-token (3.5cm): c' used
I have a table that has this command.
\begin{table}[ht]
  \centering
  \centering\caption{Table features}
\begin{tabular}{ r{3.5cm} p{5.50cm} p{5.50cm} }
\toprule
          & \multicolumn{1}{r}{} & \textbf{Income components } & \textbf{Determined in GETTSIM tax and transfer model?} \\
    \midrule
    \textbf{1} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{} & \textbf{Earned income} & No \\
          & +     & Self-employed income & No \\
          & +     & Capital income & No \\
          & +     & Rental income & No \\
          & +     & Other incomes (pensions)* & No \\
    \textbf{2} & - & \textbf{Social security contributions} & Yes \\
          & \multicolumn{1}{r}{} & \textbf{ (Old-age pensions+ employee unemployment insurance+ employee health insurance)} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{} \\
          & -     & Income tax & Yes \\
          & -     & Capital income tax & Yes \\
          & -     & Alimony advance payments & Yes \\
    \textbf{3} & +     & \textbf{Child benefit} & Yes \\
          & +     & Child-raising allowance (Child enhanced or additional Income) & Yes \\
          & +     & Unemployment benefits (no endogen. labor supply) & Yes \\
          & +     & Maternity allowance & Yes \\
    \textbf{4} & +     & \textbf{Housing allowance (HA)} & Yes \\
          & +     & Supplementary child allowance & Yes \\
          & +     & Social assistance for employable persons (SGB II) & Yes \\
          & +     & Social assistance for unemployable persons (SGB XII) & No \\
          & =     & \textbf{Net household income} & No \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%

  {\raggedright \textit{Notes}:  \footnotesize \*{*}Nevertheless, the model predicts the (updated earning points for pension claims). This table refers to the latest features at the time of writing this paper, end of 2021. Supplementary child benefits (Kinderzuschlag) is also referred to as Child Enhanced or Additional Income.\par}
  \label{Tab:table1}
\end{table}%

I get this latex error that I cannot fix, which I need to make it disappear
Package array Error: Illegal pream-token (3.5cm): `c' used.

./main.tex, 881‬
See the array package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.881 ...{tabular}{ r{3.5cm} p{5.50cm} p{5.50cm} }
                                              
Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

I have this array-relevant part in my preamble
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{#1}}


r{3.5cm} is not valid. It is just r or you can define a new column type if you need it.

Thanks a lot to all contributors! Now I understand it well. I just added the entire table. I remember some expert in the previous year suggested this way to me.. The table looks well but I still have an error in my file which is something I would like to get rid of now.

You could use wr{3.5cm}

r{3.5cm} is an error. It is just r or p{3.5cm}. Probably what you want is
 \begin{tabular}{ rc p{5.50cm} p{5.50cm} }

I don't know your page layout, so I don't know what fits, but I would recommend trying something like this
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,booktabs,tabularx,threeparttablex}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
  \centering
  \begin{threeparttable}
    \caption{Table features}
    \begin{tabularx}\linewidth{ >{\bfseries} rc XX }
      \toprule
      & & \textbf{Income components } & \textbf{Determined in GETTSIM tax and transfer model?} \\
      \midrule
      1 & & \textbf{Earned income} & No \\
      & +     & Self-employed income & No \\
      & +     & Capital income & No \\
      & +     & Rental income & No \\
      & +     & Other incomes (pensions)\tnote{*} & No \\
      2 & - & \textbf{Social security contributions} & Yes \\
      & & \textbf{ (Old-age pensions+ employee unemployment insurance+ employee health insurance)} & \\
      & -     & Income tax & Yes \\
      & -     & Capital income tax & Yes \\
      & -     & Alimony advance payments & Yes \\
      3 & +     & \textbf{Child benefit} & Yes \\
      & +     & Child-raising allowance (Child enhanced or additional Income) & Yes \\
      & +     & Unemployment benefits (no endogen. labor supply) & Yes \\
      & +     & Maternity allowance & Yes \\
      4 & +     & \textbf{Housing allowance (HA)} & Yes \\
      & +     & Supplementary child allowance & Yes \\
      & +     & Social assistance for employable persons (SGB II) & Yes \\
      & +     & Social assistance for unemployable persons (SGB XII) & No \\
      & =     & \textbf{Net household income} & No \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
    
    \footnotesize
    \begin{tablenotes}[para]
      \item[] \textit{Notes}
      \item[*] Nevertheless, the model predicts the (updated earning points for pension claims). This table refers to the latest features at the time of writing this paper, end of 2021. Supplementary child benefits (Kinderzuschlag) is also referred to as Child Enhanced or Additional Income.
    \end{tablenotes}
    \label{Tab:table1}
  \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}

The X columns will each be set to half the available width, where the total width of \linewidth includes both the first two columns (r) and (c) and the second two X columns.
The package tabularx enables this functionality.
To help with the notes, I would use either threeparttable or threeparttablex. This gives better spacing and makes it easier to typeset the marks correctly.
Finally >{\bfseries}r uses > from the array package to format every cell in that column in bold, which makes it easier if you change your mind and results in less cluttered source code.
[Unfortunately, images are unavailable due to an Okular-on-X bug, so I ask you either compile or imagine the output if you want to see the result.]

Thank you for the suggested syntax. The previous code I provided makes my table looks perfectly fine however I need to have my file clean of any errors to compile properly else-where. I followed this code above and it is incompatible with my table's dimensions. Is there a way-out? I just added the entire table

@ddocc Try \begin{tabular}{rcp{5.5cm}p{5.5cm}} That should produce a similar result without the error because LaTeX is substituting c for the {3.5cm} in your original code. However, you should know that output is not reliable following an error, so it may not give identical results.

You could use wr{3.5cm}

@DavidCarlisle does this require any extra definition in the preamble? replacing r in my code with wr give some errors still. I didn't define it in the preamble though.

no it's defined by array packagewhich is already needed for the > syntax

In
\begin{tabular}{ r{3.5cm} p{5.50cm} p{5.50cm} } r means right, p means paragraph of the length given by the argument of p. You can also use c for center and l for left. In your code {3.5cm} after r is a syntax error, as only a paragraph can have an argument.

Thanks alot for elaborating it. Kindly see my above comment.

I'd like to suggest that you adopt a tabularx-based setup, with an overall target width of \textwidth for the table, automatic bold-facing in column 1, and automatic math mode in column 2. Also, do provide some vertical whitespace (via an \addlinespace instruction) between major groups of information.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]

\caption{Table features} \label{Tab:table1}

\smallskip
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}
    >{\bfseries}l %% automatic **bold-facing**
    >{$}c<{$}     %% automatic math mode
    P{7cm} % allow automatic line-breaking
    >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X @{}}

\toprule
& & \textbf{Income components} & \textbf{Determined in GETTSIM tax and transfer model?} \\
\midrule
1 &   & \textbf{Earned income} & No \\
  & + & Self-employed income & No \\
  & + & Capital income & No \\
  & + & Rental income & No \\
  & + & Other incomes (pensions)* & No \\
\addlinespace

2 & - & \textbf{Social security contributions} & Yes \\
  &   & (Old-age pensions + employee unemployment insurance + employee health insurance) &  \\
  & - & Income tax & Yes \\
  & - & Capital income tax & Yes \\
  & - & Alimony advance payments & Yes \\
\addlinespace

3 & + & \textbf{Child benefit} & Yes \\
  & + & Child-raising allowance (Child enhanced or additional Income) & Yes \\
  & + & Unemployment benefits (no endogen. labor supply) & Yes \\
  & + & Maternity allowance & Yes \\
\addlinespace

4 & + & \textbf{Housing allowance (HA)} & Yes \\
  & + & Supplementary child allowance & Yes \\
  & + & Social assistance for employable persons (SGB II) & Yes \\
  & + & Social assistance for unemployable persons (SGB XII) & No \\
\addlinespace

  & = & \textbf{Net household income} & No \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\smallskip
\raggedright 
\footnotesize
* Nevertheless, the model predicts the (updated earning points for pension claims). 

\textit{Notes}: This table refers to the latest features at the time of writing this paper, end of 2021. Supplementary child benefits (Kinderzuschlag) is also referred to as Child Enhanced or Additional Income.
  
\end{table}%

\end{document}

